# How to loop through multiple comma separated strings in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I’m trying to loop through multiple comma separated strings with same number of commas in the string.

I’ve tried the below snippet but it doesn’t return anything.

```
#!/bin/bash
    
ip1=“Ok1,ok2,ok3”
    
ip2=“ty1,ty2,ty3”
    
for i in ${ip[@]//,/} 
do 
        echo $i 
done
```

Could someone please suggest how I can change this.

Comment: You seem to be using `ip` as if it were an array.  But `ip1` and `ip2` are strings, so `${ip[@]}` is probably not what you think it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the comma-separated string with an array as soon as feasible. If it's a hard-coded string, that's trivial:

```
ip1=(Ok1 ok2 ok3)
```

If it's from an external source (say, a command-line argument or read from a file), use `read`:

```
ip1s="Ok1,ok2,ok3"
IFS=, read -a ip1 <<< "$ips1"
```

Once you  have an array, you can use array syntax for iteration:

```
for i in "${ip1[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

If you have multiple arrays you want to iterate in lockstep, you can iterate over the keys of the arrays:

```
for i in "${!ip1[@]}"; do
  echo "${ip1[i]}"
  echo "${ip2[i]}"
done
```

(This ignores the possibility of sparse arrays, but you have to work to get those. In practice, arrays with `n` elements usually have keys 0, 1, ... `n`-1.)

Answer (score 2):

Fixes:

1. Change `ip` to `ip1` or `ip2`
2. Change the smart quotes to regular quotes: `“` → `"`
3. Replace the commas with spaces by adding a space after the final `/`

```
ip1="Ok1,ok2,ok3"
ip2="ty1,ty2,ty3"
    
for i in ${ip1//,/ }
do 
        echo "$i"
done
```

It would be better to use arrays, then the items would be naturally separated and you wouldn't have to do any string manipulation.

```
ip1=(Ok1 ok2 ok3)
ip2=(ty1 ty2 ty3)
    
for i in "${ip1[@]}"
do 
        echo "$i"
done
```